# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'foo'

Tags: hibernate, jpa, integer, sqlexception, many-to-one

I have this error "Invalid value for getInt() - 'sirocodir'" , i have search in many forum but no response for my case.

In my database the "Auteur_Id" type is a varchar(20).

My Facture Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Factures")
public class Factures implements java.io.Serializable {

private Collaborateurs collaborateurs;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Auteur_Id", nullable = false)
public Collaborateurs getCollaborateurs() {
    return this.collaborateurs;
}

public void setCollaborateurs(Collaborateurs collaborateurs) {
    this.collaborateurs = collaborateurs;
}
```

My Collaborateurs entity:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "collaborateurs")
public Set<Factures> getfactures() {
    return this.factures;
}

public void setfactures(Set<Factures> factures) {
    this.factures = factures;
}
```

My service:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Factures> AllFacturesContratsClient() {

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Factures").list();
}
```

Log tomcat:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'sirocodir'
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2725)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2813)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(DelegatingResultSet.java:237)
at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:51)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:186)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:175)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:158)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1443)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1371)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1271)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:619)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
... 126 more
```

Comment: Where is the code that calls `getInt()`?

Comment: 'sirocodir' (or any other varchar, which kind of is rather like 'String' ) is not a valid int.

Comment: There is no code who call getInt(). Dont know why he call it.

Comment: Stultuske: in my database the type of the row is a varchar(20) not a int.

Comment: Check your mapping. You most likely mapped a field as int that is a char/varchar.

Comment: I have found any mapping as int in my class.

Comment: any conclusion on this one?

Answer (score 27):

Do you have any enum type in the class `Collaborateurs` ?
If it has, make sure use `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`

Answer (score 1):

I got this after making a schema change.  Probably the migration didn't work right.  After dropping the table and regenerating it, the error went away.

Comment: did you lose data?

Comment: Did you truncate it? Or run a repair?

Answer (score 0):

This exception also occurs due to incorrect mapping between entities.  In our case we had wrong relationship mapping between two entities.  We resolved this by correcting relationship among entities.